# ng new app package error

Tags: angular, npm

Can't generate a new fresh app using angular cli. Seems like a package giving error. How to solve this?

Summary:

> npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near
>   '...7w\nr0sNcY3SWENyNwkKN'

Log:

> 2213 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while
>   parsing near '...7w\nr0sNcY3SWENyNwkKN' 2213 verbose stack     at
>   JSON.parse () 2213 verbose stack     at parseJson
>   (D:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\node_modules\json-parse-better-errors\index.js:7:17)
>   2213 verbose stack     at consumeBody.call.then.buffer (D:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\body.js:96:50)
>   2213 verbose stack     at  2213 verbose stack     at
>   process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7) 2214
>   verbose cwd D:\VSCode\helloAng 2215 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134 2216
>   verbose argv "D:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "D:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "--quiet"
>   2217 verbose node v8.11.1 2218 verbose npm  v5.6.0 2219 error
>   Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near
>   '...7w\nr0sNcY3SWENyNwkKN' 2220 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This probably happens because of a caching problem.
Run `npm cache clean --force` in the command-line and try again!